# sumar todos los valores de una columna en mysql y WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

tengo un pequeño problema con WordPress y Mysql, el tema es que estoy intentando sumar todos los valores numéricos de una columna pero de momento solo consigo que me devuelva el valor de la primera fila, el código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
global $wpdb; $usuarios_table = $wpdb->prefix."usuarios"; $sumtotal = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT person, SUM(person) FROM $usuarios_table" ); foreach ($sumtotal as $st) {echo $st->person;}
```

Con este código como digo solo consigo que se imprima el primer valor de la primera fila, y yo necesito que me sume todos los valores de la columna.

Gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido.

Si quieres sumar los valores con MySql puede hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(person) as total FROM $usuarios_table;  
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo $row["total"];
```

En la primera variable tengo la sentencia SQL para sumar los valores y me los muestre en una tabla  que se llamará total.

En la variable row,la sentencia `mysql_fetch_array` de php sirve para volcar datos, provenientes de una consulta mysql, dentro de un array php.

Y la tercera línea es un `echo` para mostrarla.

Comment: esta sentencia en WordPress me da un error y no me carga la pagina, no me funciona como debería compañero

Comment: Puedes escribir el error? Así podemos ayudarte a mejorar y sabre el problema.